# Leave at least one item in sortable JQuery UI List

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two connected sortable lists.  I don't want the user to be able to leave a list empty.  They must have at least one item in the list at all times.

I was trying to do something a long the lines of:

```
    $( "#unused, #used" ).sortable( {
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable", 
        placeholder: "placeholder",
        items: "li:not(:only-child)"
        }).disableSelection();
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: sorry that example doesnt throw an error "li(:only-child)" throws the error (:only-child) not recognised

Comment: Well, of course it did, for it should have been `li:only-child`. However, I believe this snippet will only not remove the last remaining item if it is the only item already in the list when sorting. I don't know my way around jUI too good, but are there any callback parameters? You'll have to gradually check whether, for example, the item being currently sorted or maybe the item about to be removed is the last item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [cancel](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-cancel) option instead of [items](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-items):

```
$( "#unused, #used" ).sortable( {
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable", 
    placeholder: "placeholder",
    cancel: "li:only-child"
});
```

This option will prevent sorting when only one item left in the sortable list.

See a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VPNP4/1/).

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be your use of `:not` vs `not()` but couldnt say for sure. Overall selectors can be a pain sometimes, in how you attempt to map them out for various needs.

try `$(this + 'li').not(':only-child')`

if that doesn't work then try

`$(this + 'li:not:only-child')`